# What middleware can i use to store data in React Application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've developed a React Application that has form where users can update their Birthdate along with their ID. All my team members would be able to access the Application through http://<IP Address>/3000 When each person updates the form the data should to stored in my Local machine.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What happens if you kill the app? Would the data still exist?

Comment: ya thats what i want, rather than calling the API and storing the data in DB, what other alternative I can use?

Comment: Any particular reason why do you want to use a middleware (e,g want to process the data before hand). What's stopping you from using a regular `array` or an object?

Comment: If I use React's state the data will be lost when the application is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot handle this in the client side, because you do not have a mutual state that is shared amongst you and your friends.

One possible solution, given your requirements, is to use a global data structure that you can put somewhere in the  **backend** of your react app. This is so that your friend would be able to access the same data as you. There are a number of ways you can do this, depending on how you set up your react application. What I would do is set up 2 RESTful endpoints in your react project's backend. So, something like:

1. GET /data
2. POST /data

In the handler of both endpoints you'd be able to access the data that you declared. Now, each time you want to update your shared data, just make a network request to the above endpoints.